# Inequality with floor function supremum infimum

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $A =  \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^+ : x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \leq \frac{3}{4} \}$, with $\lfloor x \rfloor=\max \{d \in \mathbb{Z}: d\leq x  \}$.

Find, $\sup{A}$  and  $\inf{A}$.

If $x>1$, $\frac{1}{x} < 1$, then $x \lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor =0 \leq \frac{3}{4}$. We see that does not exist $\sup{A}$.

On the other hand, $0<x\leq 1 \implies \frac{1}{x} \geq 1  \implies \lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor \geq 1$. Then, $x \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \rfloor \geq x$...

How do I find $\inf{A}$?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: $\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor =1  \iff 1 \leq \frac{1}{x} <2  \iff 1 \geq x >\frac{1}{2} $. Then, 
$$x \cdot 1 \leq \frac{3}{4}  \iff S_1= \left ]\frac{1}{2} , \frac{3}{4} \right ] $$

Case 2: $\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor =2  \iff 2 \leq \frac{1}{x} <3  \iff \frac{1}{2} \geq x >\frac{1}{3} $. Then, 
$$x \cdot 2 \leq \frac{3}{4}  \iff S_2= \left ]\frac{1}{3} , \frac{3}{8} \right ] $$

Case 3: $\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor =3  \iff 3 \leq \frac{1}{x} <4  \iff \frac{1}{3} \geq x >\frac{1}{4} $. Then, 
$$x \cdot 3 \leq \frac{3}{4}  \iff S_3= \emptyset  $$

General Case: $\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor =n  \iff n \leq \frac{1}{x} < n+1  \iff \frac{1}{n} \geq x >\frac{1}{n+1} $. Then, 
$$x \cdot n \leq \frac{3}{4}  \iff x \leq \frac{3}{4n} \iff S_n=  \left ]\frac{1}{n+1} , \frac{3}{4n} \right ]= \emptyset \text{ if } n \geq 3.$$

Therefore, $\inf{A}=\frac{1}{3}$.